# What is the relation between linear transformations with the same matrix on different bases?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Given two linear transformations $$Tx=Ax$$ and $$T'y=Ay$$ where $x$ and $y$ are two different bases of a vector space $V$, how are those linear transformations related?

Suppose that $$y=Px$$ where $P$ is the change of basis matrix, then I have $$T'x=APx$$
I can't see how $T=Ax$ and $T'=APx$ relate to each other, perhaps if it was true that $AP=PA$ then $$T'=APx=PAx=PTx$$ but $AP=PA$ is not necessarily true, so what is their relations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal A:=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $\mathcal B=(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ be two bases of $V$, and let $P:V\to V$ be the base change map $a_i\mapsto b_i$.

The condition that linear map $T$ has the same matrix in basis $\mathcal A$ as map $T'$ in basis $\mathcal B$ should rather be translated as follows:

- for every index $i$, we have $[Ta_i]_{\mathcal A}\ =\ [T'b_i]_{\mathcal B}$, where $[x]_{\mathcal A}$ denotes the coordinate vector of $x$ in basis $\mathcal A$.

By the base of change formula, we have $[x]_{\mathcal A}=[Px]_{\mathcal B}$ for every $x\in V$. (It's obvious for the basis elements and we can use linearity.)
So, the above condition is equivalent to $PTa_i=T'b_i$, or, using $b_i=Pa_i$, to
$$PTa_i=T'Pa_i\,.$$
And thus, it holds if and only if $PT=T'P$, or, put another way, $T'=PTP^{-1}$.

Since any invertible map can be viewed as a base-of-change map, we obtained that the answer is that $T$ and $T'$ are *conjugate*.